# peticion a la base de datos con laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

tengo una consulta sobre como realizar una petición a la base de datos con laravel, tengo una tabla categorías y otra productos cada producto pertenece a una categoría  relacionados en la tabla productos por el campo category_id, lo que necesito hacer es que obtener el listado de las categorias pero que además cada categoría me entregue solo los últimos 4 productos que le pertenecen

Estaba trabajando con algo así:

```
public function index(){
        $products = Product::orderBy('id','DESC')->where('status','PUBLISHED')->paginate(6);
        $categories = Category::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate();
        return view('web.inicio', compact('products','categories'));
    }


@foreach($categories as $category)

      <div class="tab-pane show" id="news-{{ $category->id }}" role="tabpanel">
          <div class="row">
              @foreach($category->products as $product)
                producto
              @endforeach
          </div>
      </div>

@endforeach
```

pero esto me entrega todos los productos de cada categoría, necesito limitarla a las ultimas 4. Ayuda please

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que lo pudieras solventar del siguiente modo:

- Tener un modelo `Product`
- Tener un modelo `Category`
- Hacer uso de las relaciones de Eloquent (en este caso tu relación parece indicar de 1:N)
- Hacemos uso de *eager loading*
- Hacemos uso de `latest` para ordenar descendentemente por medio de la columna `created_at`; en caso de no existir dicha columna puedes especificar alguna otra en los parántesis de dicha función para que haga el ordenamiento
- Hacemos uso de `take` para indicar por medio de un entero la cantidad de elementos que deseamos retornar

**Modelos**

```
class Category extends Model 
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}


class Product extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

**Consulta**

Ahora en tu controlador prueba la siguiente consulta para traer los datos de las categorías con sus productos asociados

```
$categories = Category::with(['products' => fn($query) => $query->latest()->take(4)])->get();
```

**Referencia**

- [eager loading en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: hola gracias por la respuesta, he realizado los pasos pero al momento de entregarme los productos solo me entrega 4 últimos productos de todo el listado de categorías, si añado a otra categoría un producto borra de algún lado para seguirme mostrando solo 4 productos en total de todo el listado, podrías revisarlo? Muchas gracias

Comment: Dame un momento @jofret